# pywin32 SetFocus resulting in 'Access is denied' error

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I'm creating a script that will send mouse inputs to a specific window. The only way I have found to do this is by setting focus to the window. If there is another way please explain it.
Anyways, this is the code that is not working.

```py
from win32gui import *
us_ip = input('Version of Minecraft: ')

minecraft_handle = FindWindow(None, f'Minecraft {us_ip}')
SetFocus(minecraft_handle)
```

I can retrieve the HWND but when I run the program I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Jacob Daniels\Desktop\python\autoclicker\windows api experimentation\py.py", line 5, in <module>
    SetFocus(minecraft_handle)
pywintypes.error: (5, 'SetFocus', 'Access is denied.')
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Documentation for library:
http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32_modules.html
edit: posted wrong error message

Comment: Try `print(minecraft_handle)` before setting the focus.

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks for responding. I did that and the handle matched up like expected. Sorry, I've been on a trip and I just got back. This question is still open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[MS.Docs]: SetFocus function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setfocus) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Sets the keyboard focus to the specified window. **The window must be attached to the calling thread's message queue**.
>
> ...
>
> By using the [AttachThreadInput function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-attachthreadinput), a thread can attach its input processing to another thread. **This allows a thread to call SetFocus to set the keyboard focus to a window attached to another thread's message queue**.

Obviously the "remote" window is not attached to the *Python* script (main) thread, so that needs to be taken care of (with a bit of extra work).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import win32gui as wgui
import win32process as wproc
import win32api as wapi


def main(*argv):
    if not argv:
        window_name = input("Enter window name: ")
    else:
        window_name = argv[0]

    handle = wgui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
    print("Window `{0:s}` handle: 0x{1:016X}".format(window_name, handle))
    if not handle:
        print("Invalid window handle")
        return
    remote_thread, _ = wproc.GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle)
    wproc.AttachThreadInput(wapi.GetCurrentThreadId(), remote_thread, True)
    prev_handle = wgui.SetFocus(handle)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q062649124]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py "Untitled - Notepad"
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Window `Untitled - Notepad` handle: 0x0000000004A520AA
>
> Done.
> ```

Needless to say that the *Notepad* window popped up in front of *Cmd* terminal. 
Note that for some windows, it might not work.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I didn't get the notification until I looked at the website.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been doing homework all and haven't had an opportunity to try it out. But, after looking at the API, I realized my mistake. Even if your specific solution doesn't function I will be able to figure it out myself. (But I believe it will :))

Comment: Note that you should only accept an answer once it solves your problem. I wasn't trying to pressure you with my comment, but sometimes after their problem is solved, people forget about this step (which was not your case).

Comment: This solution still gives me the 'Access is denied' error. Any other ideas how to fix it, please?

Comment: Which line is triggering the error?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was trying to switch from a window which was hidden to the command line where Python is running.

Comment: However, in rare cases, I am getting the error: "pywintypes.error: (87, 'AttachThreadInput', 'The parameter is incorrect.')". when calling `win32api.GetCurrentThreadId(), threadId, True)`. It seems random, as sometimes the same window works.

Comment: I guess it doesn't like the *threadId* argument. Maybe the other window belongs to a process not started by the current user? Your user is not an *Administrator* I assume.